# installation of tensorflowonspark in windows 7

Tags: python, windows, apache-spark, tensorflow

Am very new to Tensorflow on Spark. I have installed tensorflow and spark on my system but am unable to run tensorflowonspark from the cmd prompt in windows 7.

Am getting error as shown below. How do i rectify it? And Why is it showing this error?

```
 enC:\>python -m pip install --upgrade tensorflowonspark
Collecting tensorflowonspark
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 335, in run

    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_
files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 554, in _prepare
_file
    require_hashes
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 278, in popu
late_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 465, in find_requireme
nt
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 423, in find_all_candi
dates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 568, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 683, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 811, in get_page
    inst = cls(resp.content, resp.url, resp.headers)
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 731, in __init__
    namespaceHTMLElements=False,
TypeError: parse() got an unexpected keyword argument 'transport_encoding'ter code here
```

Comment: This command installs ```TensorFlowOnSpark``` on your system. If it is already installed, you may want to follow the tutorial [here](https://github.com/yahoo/TensorFlowOnSpark/wiki/Conversion-Guide)

Comment: @ddg do u mean that i don't need to separately install "TensorFlowOnSpark" if i have already installed these two softwares(tensorflow and spark) independently previously?

Comment: Oh sorry, I misread your question. You **do** need to separately install "TensorFlowOnSpark". If you have not downloaded it before, or your interpreter doesn't have the package installed, I would try just ```pip3 install tensorflowonspark``` without the ```--upgrade``` flag.

Comment: @ddg Thanks a Lot! actually i was using python 3.5 version so had to use py -m pip install tensorflowonspark to get it working... Thanks